# BLE sensor not found by scan but connected over BT dongle/ virtual com

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dongle

Colleagues, following situation: I'm trying to develop application which works with a BLE sensor (BLE112). I was provided with a current applicaiton which works from Desktop PC and includes BT/USB dongle which installs itself as virtual com port.

Now something I just do not get: the dongle finds the sensor and can connect to it. But the sensor is not visible to any scan programm as BLE device - I cannot see it.

How can it be? From what I know BLE device must advertise itself in order to be able to connect with it. So because the dongle can connect, it should be advertising itself, but it's not visible!

Comment: What do you mean with "the dongle finds the sensor and can connect to it"? How can you connect to something you don't even see?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, mystery solved:  in this setup the dongle turned out to be a periperial device which advertises itself, and then the sensor connects to it. Thanks everyone!